# How Can I stop insertion of assembly information whlie using WriteXml

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am using IXmlSerializable interface for conversion of Dataset table objects in to XML format.

Please find the class example below.

```
public class SecondaryRNCTable: IXmlSerializable
{
    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        IP = reader.GetAttribute("IP");
        int count = int.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("count"));
        reader.ReadStartElement();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement();
            SecondaryRNC rnc = new SecondaryRNC();
            rnc.ReadXml(reader);
            Add(rnc);
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("IP", parentDOMIP);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("count", Count.ToString());
        writer.WriteStartElement("SecondaryRNCs");

        foreach (SecondaryRNC rnc in this)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("SecondaryRNC");
            rnc.WriteXml(writer);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
     }
}
```

we add multiple datatables in a dataset say ds and `ds.writeXML(GZipOutputStream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)` is invoked to write in outputstream. So for some tables, it also write assembly information shown below.

> msdata:InstanceType="NeighborList.SecondaryRNCTable, projectName,
>   Version=14.0.0.12, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2e771ef06d8dbb7"

How can I stop this insertion of string while writing in to outputstream?

Please provide input ASAP.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to pass it into an XSLT transformer, which will allow you to format the XML however you want.